# HP ProLiant DL380p G8 and 32GB LRDIMM where to populate (cant get it working)

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

i have HP ProLiant DL380p G8 with 2 E5-2690v2
in HP manual   32GB LRDIMM "HP 32GB (1x32GB) Quad Rank x4 PC3-14900L (DDR3-1866) Load Reduced CAS-13 Memory Kit"  708643-B21 is supported
i own 4 Pcs of this RAM but i cant make them works 
tried all channels and slots using 4 or 2 pcs 
iLO shows 
232-Memory initialization Error no usable memory detected
or 
 memory channel not populated in correct order if i use another slots
,Can anyone help me with this ??
thanks in Advance

Zaid

Comment: Have you tried to start this server with another memory?

Comment: I have an old same PN RAM and it works alone even if i put new 3 RAM with it, it reads 32 GBs only  ( in bios it shows 128GBs)

Comment: Have you tried to update firmware to latest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned these RAMs back to supplier and he test them and face the same issue

i guess its a broken items

Thanks to you all

Zaid

Answer (score 1):

Install them on below order:

1st RAM: 12A
2nd RAM: 9B
Refer [HPE reference](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0109346)

Comment: i tried but same issue

Comment: 1. Reseat the RAM at 12A on CPU1. 
2. Resear the RAM at 12A on CPU2. 
3. Please share is there any error shown. 
BTW, what is the Partcode for this server? 665554-B21?